# Error configuring SSL on Apache 2.4 on Windows

Tags: windows, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, apache2.4

I have a windows server VM, running server 2019, on a company network, and it is to be used as a web server with Apache. I have got a copy of apache 2.4 installed on it and it serves http pages just fine, but I am trying to set up SSl for https connections.

I have been talked through using the MMC to add the certificates snap in then using this to generate a request. (This is AKA the key file I think?) and sent this file to the necessary admin in the business to provide me with a ceritificate so that the users browsers display a green address bar when visiting the site via https on the company intranet.

They sent me back the following files:

```
certnew.cer   
certnew.p7b   
intermediate.cer
root.cer
```

I then did a lot of googling and found various gides about how to use these files, and I have come to the following conclusions: (please correct if wrong).

- Cer files and crt files are the same thing. They can have some kind
  of different encoding in the contents, but you generaly use a .cer
  file in the same place(s) you could use a .crt file, so if Apache
  instructions are mentioning one, I can probably use the other and
  just rename the file extension.
- The file I sent off was the private key file that I will need to use
  in the SSL configuration.
- There was some kind of changes between Apache 2.4 and earlier
  versions, so I should be carefull when looking at guides about SSL to
  ensure it's correct for 2.4 versions.
- I need to enable SSL in the main http config file and add the details for my certificate files and server into the httpd-ssl.conf file

The relivant part of that file currently looks like this:

```
    <VirtualHost *:443>
    
    #   General setup for the virtual host
    DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs"
    ServerName <servername>
    ServerAdmin <internal email>
    ErrorLog "${SRVROOT}/logs/error.log"
    TransferLog "${SRVROOT}/logs/access.log"
    
    #   SSL Engine Switch:
    #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
    SSLEngine on
    
    #   Server Certificate:
    #   Point SSLCertificateFile at a PEM encoded certificate.  If
    #   the certificate is encrypted, then you will be prompted for a
    #   pass phrase.  Note that a kill -HUP will prompt again.  Keep
    #   in mind that if you have both an RSA and a DSA certificate you
    #   can configure both in parallel (to also allow the use of DSA
    #   ciphers, etc.)
    #   Some ECC cipher suites (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4492.txt)
    #   require an ECC certificate which can also be configured in
    #   parallel.
    SSLCertificateFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/primary.crt"
    #SSLCertificateFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/server-dsa.crt"
    #SSLCertificateFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/server-ecc.crt"
    
    #   Server Private Key:
    #   If the key is not combined with the certificate, use this
    #   directive to point at the key file.  Keep in mind that if
    #   you've both a RSA and a DSA private key you can configure
    #   both in parallel (to also allow the use of DSA ciphers, etc.)
    #   ECC keys, when in use, can also be configured in parallel
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/private.key"
    #SSLCertificateKeyFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/server-dsa.key"
    #SSLCertificateKeyFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/server-ecc.key"
    
    #   Server Certificate Chain:
    #   Point SSLCertificateChainFile at a file containing the
    #   concatenation of PEM encoded CA certificates which form the
    #   certificate chain for the server certificate. Alternatively
    #   the referenced file can be the same as SSLCertificateFile
    #   when the CA certificates are directly appended to the server
    #   certificate for convenience.
    SSLCertificateChainFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/certificate.crt"
    
    #   Certificate Authority (CA):
    #   Set the CA certificate verification path where to find CA
    #   certificates for client authentication or alternatively one
    #   huge file containing all of them (file must be PEM encoded)
    #   Note: Inside SSLCACertificatePath you need hash symlinks
    #         to point to the certificate files. Use the provided
    #         Makefile to update the hash symlinks after changes.
    #SSLCACertificatePath "${SRVROOT}/conf/root.cer"
    SSLCACertificateFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/root.cer"
```

So I took a copy of the files I had been sent, as well as my key file I sent to them, and renamed them as above so they are refrenced in the ssl config file.

When I try to start the apache service, it fails if I enable SSL in the main http file with a generic error. (but still works fine when i comment out the SSL in the main conf file.) So I then tried to launch the httpd.exe file from a command prompt to get some error that is more helpful, and after running the file with no error responce, I checked in the error logs, and the following lines of errors are shown for my most recent attempt:

```
[Sun Oct 30 15:06:02.661255 2022] [ssl:emerg] [pid 3484:tid 512] AH02577: Init: SSLPassPhraseDialog builtin is not supported on Win32 (key file D:/Apache24/conf/private.key)
[Sun Oct 30 15:06:02.661255 2022] [ssl:emerg] [pid 3484:tid 512] AH02311: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting. See D:/Apache24/logs/error.log for more information
[Sun Oct 30 15:06:02.661255 2022] [ssl:emerg] [pid 3484:tid 512] AH02564: Failed to configure encrypted (?) private key <servername>:443:0, check D:/Apache24/conf/private.key
[Sun Oct 30 15:06:02.661255 2022] [ssl:emerg] [pid 3484:tid 512] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag
[Sun Oct 30 15:06:02.661255 2022] [ssl:emerg] [pid 3484:tid 512] SSL Library Error: error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error (Type=PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO)
[Sun Oct 30 15:06:02.661255 2022] [ssl:emerg] [pid 3484:tid 512] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag
[Sun Oct 30 15:06:02.661255 2022] [ssl:emerg] [pid 3484:tid 512] SSL Library Error: error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_template_noexp_d2i:nested asn1 error
[Sun Oct 30 15:06:02.661255 2022] [ssl:emerg] [pid 3484:tid 512] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag
[Sun Oct 30 15:06:02.661255 2022] [ssl:emerg] [pid 3484:tid 512] SSL Library Error: error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error (Type=RSAPrivateKey)
[Sun Oct 30 15:06:02.661255 2022] [ssl:emerg] [pid 3484:tid 512] SSL Library Error: error:04093004:rsa routines:old_rsa_priv_decode:RSA lib
[Sun Oct 30 15:06:02.661255 2022] [ssl:emerg] [pid 3484:tid 512] SSL Library Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag
[Sun Oct 30 15:06:02.661255 2022] [ssl:emerg] [pid 3484:tid 512] SSL Library Error: error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error (Type=PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO)
AH00016: Configuration Failed
```

I don't really know what any of that means, but I'm guessing it's teling me there is something wrong with my private key file, but I have no idea how to tell what is wrong or how to fix it. I have checked that the modules for ssl are enabled in the main apache conf file.

Can anyone provide any guidence?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Meta: this Q is not programming or development and is arguably multiple questions, but this semi-A is much too long for comments. I will delete (or agree to a mod deleting) if needed.

> request ... is AKA the key file I think?

Absolutely not, and I think this is most of your problem. The whole security of 'public-key' cryptography, also called 'asymmetric', is based on you not ever sending, giving, or otherwise providing your private key to anyone else.
The 'request' is a [CSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_signing_request) and is basically temporary; once the certificate is issued the CSR is no longer needed or used. If you want to be tidy, you could delete it.

> users browsers display a green address bar

The green bar was only for Extended Validation (EV) certificates, which from real public CAs cost quite a bit of money. It's possible your company has tweaked all the PCs (or all the relevant ones) to accept an internal or ad-hoc CA as valid for EV, but I don't see why they'd bother, as browsers dropped the green bar several years ago. What you get now is a padlock on the URL/address bar for HTTPS with *any* valid certificate (regardless of validation class), and for an invalid certificate you get either a warning/error icon modifying or replacing the padlock and/or a complete warning/error page.

> Cer files and crt files are the same thing ... I can probably ... just rename the file extension.

Kind of. There are two main encodings used for *a* (single) certificate in a file and some other places: DER also called binary, and PEM also (and incorrectly) called by Microsoft base64. People variously use both extensions `.cer .crt` (and sometimes others as well) for both formats. Much software can use both, but httpd can only use PEM -- in a file with any name or extension, even `FeeblyGorp.snork` if that's what you want.

However, an HTTPS server actually needs (in addition to the privatekey) not just *a* certificate but a *chain* consisting of several (almost always at least 2, and usually 3 or 4) certificates. There is more variation in handling such a chain. The simpler way is just to take the certificates and concatenate them. Another way that developed in the past and is still used is a [particular type of PKCS7 message](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_7) which *conventionally* has the extension `.p7b` or `.p7c` (although again most programs can handle any name, in spite of Microsoft persistently trying to make you believe a filename's extension somehow controls the content, which it does not and never did). Apache supports only the plain-sequence in PEM method, not the PKCS7 method.

> The file I sent off [the CSR] was the private key file

No. See above.

> There was some kind of changes between Apache 2.4 and earlier versions, so I should be carefull when looking at guides about SSL to ensure it's correct for 2.4 versions.

There are changes not just between the 2.2 and 2.4 'families', but between point releases within 2.4. Search [the documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html) for "version 2.4." to see. If you try to use something that is newer than the version you are running it will almost certainly give an error message, but if you use an older feature it will still work on newer versions with very rare exceptions.

> I need to enable SSL in the main http config file and add the details for my certificate files and server into the httpd-ssl.conf file

Not really. httpd reads one config file initially, and *if* that file contains one or more `<Include>` directives referring to other files it reads them also; I expect that is what you mean by 'enable SSL in the main config file' -- you're not enabling SSL as such, you're using a file that happens to provide SSL configuration. httpd can handle all the config in one file just fine, but *people* often find it more convenient to put logical 'pieces' such as different vhosts, or in your case the SSL config, in separate files that can be named to reflect each one's contents. In short, you must add the SSL related config, but you aren't required to put it in a separate file with a specific name.

So, net, your problem is that you need the privatekey in a file usable by httpd, meaning one of a few PEM formats. When you create a certificate request with MMC/cert it stores the privatekey within the Windows certificate store in a hidden location; normally when you get the resulting cert from the CA you load it into the same store with MMC and it is matched up with the hidden privatekey so that Windows-specific programs like IIS can use both of them together. Once you do that it *may* be possible to export the privatekey with the cert as a PFX/PKCS12 file, which httpd cannot use directly but which can be converted to suitable PEM file(s) using OpenSSL if you have or get that. However, if the key is marked unexportable, you're out of luck.

The *usual* (and simple) way to get a cert for httpd is OpenSSL: it can create the privatekey *in a PEM file* and the CSR, and when you get back the cert (and chain) you just combine them with the privatekey you already have.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply Dave. My next step is to either generate a new request and ask that they make the files they return to me exportable (the CSR was set to be exportable last time, but the key still seems to not be exportable in MMC, or I'm looking in the wrong place, (personal certificates is where everything has been going atm.)) or to figure out how to use open SSL to do it, and hope they can also use the resulting CSR from open SSL to get me the same files.

Don't suppose you know any good docs for using open SSL do it in a Windows enviroment? I'll do some googling anyway.

Comment: Anseur: all certificates are always exportable; it is the privatekey created by _you_ as part of the request that is or isn't. We have hundreds of existing Qs on using OpenSSL (just put 'openssl create csr' in the search box) but for basics try my first few google hits: https://www.ssl.com/how-to/manually-generate-a-certificate-signing-request-csr-using-openssl/ https://www.thesslstore.com/knowledgebase/ssl-generate/csr-generation-guide-for-nginx-openssl/ https://sectigo.com/resource-library/how-to-generate-certificate-signing-request-on-apache-mod-ssl-openssl